# Why does Qt renderer rebuild all batches every frame

Tags: qt, optimization, qml, qt5, renderer

I have about 20 batches in my app and most of them are rendered using my shaders via ShaderEffect QML node. I want to optimize my app to run smoothly on i.MX6 Solo, so I profiled it with `QSG_RENDERER_DEBUG=render`. And I saw a couple of strange things in the output:

```
Renderer::render() QSGAbstractRenderer(0x2500db17e30) "rebuild: full"
Rendering:
 -> Opaque: 52 nodes in 9 batches...
 -> Alpha: 26 nodes in 11 batches...
 - 0x25012c17e70 [  upload] [noclip] [opaque] [  merged]  Nodes:   13  Vertices:    52  Indices:   104  root: 0x0
...
 - 0x25012bbecc0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:    56  Indices:    84  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 -> times: build: 0, prepare(opaque/alpha): 0/0, sorting: 0, upload(opaque/alpha): 0/0, render: 3
```

Every single frame all batches are rebuilt, even though most of them never change. I found that there is one text item that triggers this full rebuild. When I disable it, stop updating it or use `clip: true` on it, it no longer triggers a full rebuild. This text item has a unique size, so it lives in a separate batch and should not interfere with any other batches. I don't understand such behavior. Is it a Qt renderer bug?

The second weird thing is that I have a ShaderEffect with a GridMesh resolution 1x40. I never move it. I just change a couple of its uniforms and draw something with a different shader above it. However, this mesh uploads every frame.

Why does Qt scene graph upload meshes when it could easily reuse them? How to force it not to do so? I tried `clip: true` but it doesn't help with the second issue. I think that defining geometry in C++ can help. I haven't written any Qt render code in C++ so far, so I'm looking for ways to do it entirely in QML.

Comment: You should provide a minimal, complete example.

Comment: I asked this question in the hope that someone shares their experience of unexpected reasons for batch rebuilds. However, you're right, I will try to extract a minimal example and update my question.